# How to config SystemJS to load typescript folder modules?

Tags: typescript, systemjs

In Typescript, you can have a folder with index.ts in it, and you can load the module by specifying just the folder name. For example

```
src/
  index.ts
  ..
```

you can import with `import * from './src';`

The problem is that when you use this with SystemJS (Angular 2 for example), it will be looking for src.js where the src folder is. How do I configure SystemJS to look for either src.js or src/index.js?

Comment: You can probably do it using [map](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map) but wouldn't it be easier to just `import * from './src/index';`?

Comment: yeah, but I have libraries written using the more idiomatic typescript style. Having to go through and change all the code is just painful.

Comment: What is the " idiomatic typescript style"?

Answer (score 0):

If the transpiled js file is in the same folder as it's corresponding ts file("/src" folder in your case), you will need to tell systemjs to use js as it's default extension.

```
SystemJS.config({
        packages: {
            '/src': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });

    SystemJS.import("/src/index.js");
```